# Activity not destroying properely and multiple instances are created which are not required

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application with two activities A and B. On clicking on list item in activity A it takes me to the activity B.
For the first time the activity works fine.
Now I have a broadcast reciever which throws me a notification , on clicking on that notification it takes me to the activity B.

The problem is when i am allready on activity B and the new notification comes and when i click on it it relaunches the same activity.When i press back the activity is not destroyed properly as i am getting logs of previous Activity B when i am currently on Activity B.

I have tried out allmost all suitable flags like Intent.Flag_Clear top etc...
But it isnt helping me out.
My activity sometimes works fine and sometimes doesnt work properely.
Please help me out stuck on this problem since a week

Comment: in `AndroidManifest.xml` use `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity. This will destroy make your activity B destroyed whenever you leave it.

Comment: @Rohan khandwal I jave allready tried that but still getting logs of allready destroyed activity

Answer (score 0):

I think the launchmode attribute in your Manifest will do the trick. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html and scroll down to the launchmode.

singleTask or singleInstance sounds like it is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can change the launch mode of your activity on the manifest file. See this activity attribute: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 0):

in `AndroidManifest.xml` use `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity. This will destroy your activity B destroyed whenever you leave it.

Comment: Rohan khandwal I jave allready tried that but still getting logs of allready destroyed activity

Comment: @UditKapahi what do you mean by still getting the logs? From what i am understanding, when you are on activity B and you open activity B again through notification, you are getting two activity B. Means when you press back button you will get another B, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. But when i use this with Flag_clear_top with single top it doesnt load two activities, but then i am again getting the logs of previousy opened instance.

Comment: @UditKapahi I am not getting what do you mean by "getting log from previous activity". PLease post the `logcat` showing what you are getting and what you want.